# How to explicitly set the date for a letter -- to avoid it defaulting to today?

Tags: lyx, letters, date, lyx-layouts

I have several `.lyx` files from circa 2000, which I need to reprint. I didn't preserve the corresponding `.pdf` (or `.ps`) files, so I need to regenerate those.

Modern LyX has no problem with that *except*, the newly-generated PDFs all bear *today's* date, which wouldn't do...

The documents are all using the standard Letter-class (the KOMA2 letter didn't exist back then, I guess), and there is no *explicit* date-field anywhere.

How can I modify the files to print the date I need -- without leaving the comfort of LyX GUI?..

(There are several questions about this topic, but none of them are about LyX...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Based on your statement that"there is no explicit date-field anywhere" in the old documents, I'm guessing that that the underlying tex files contained explicit `\date{}` statements. Do see if adding a `\date{}` statement gets you where you want to be.

Comment: Where would I put this statement? Keep in mind, I'm not editing the `.tex` file directly -- I'm using LyX...

Comment: Do you know about ERTs?

Comment: No idea, what "ERT" even stands for...

Comment: "evil red tag" -- a standard term for lyx users. Google it for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it -- Insert->TeX code (I did it right before the Opening), then type in `\date{May 26, 2000}` and it worked. Surprised, I had to resort to this, though.

The letters I compose today (using KOMA Script 2) all have the Date type, where I can explicitly set the date. But no one added it to the older Letter?

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

## Easy (using KOMA-Script letter):

For KOMA-Script letter class, there would be a selector in the LyX toolbar to input the date. Just use:

[image: selector]

Now, you can input the date like other letter elements:

[image: input date]

Despite adding TeX code is always possible, you should prefer LyX commands. And in this case LyX uses correctly the KOMA-Script command `\setkomavar{date}{May 26, 2000}` to setup the date, because I'm using the KOMA-Script letter class.

## Easy (using standard letter class):

When using the standard letter class, IMHO it would be a good idea to use the document settings to add the date to the preamble:

[image: date via preamble]

## Advanced (using standard letter class with new layout setting):

A suggestion for experienced LyX users would be to add a local layout, e.g., also in the document settings:

[image: layout settings]

You first have to validate the layout before applying it.

Now, you have the date element in the `Letter` section:

[image: date element]

To be able to easy copy the element, here the code of the element:

```
Style Date
        Category              Letter
        Margin                Static
        LatexType             Command
        LatexName             date
        KeepEmpty             1
        LeftMargin            Signature:xx
        LabelSep              xx
        TopSep                0.4
        BottomSep             0.4
        ParSep                0.4
        Align                 Block
        AlignPossible         Block, Left
        LabelType             Static
        LabelString           "Date:"
        LabelFont
          Series              Bold
          Shape               Italic
          Color               red
        EndFont
End
```

## LyX experts (new document type based on standard letter class):

Very experienced users also can add a new document type `Letter (Standard Class with date)`. To do so
save the layout code above as `letterdate.inc`. Now you can generate the new letter layout file `letterwithdate.layout`:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[letter]{Letter (Standard Class with date)}
#  \DeclareCategory{Letters}
# Letter textclass definition file based on letter.layout

Input letter.layout
Input letterdate.inc
```

Copy both files into the `layouts` directory of your LyX installation (to be usable by all LyX users) or the `layouts` directory of the LyX settings of you users (with Linux usually `~/.lyx/layouts/`). Now select `Tools` → `Reconfigure` in LyX. After the next LyX restart the new class should be available.